# where to store request.json file

Tags: video-intelligence-api

I am trying out Google video intelligent api by following the quick start guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/getting-started#set_up_your_project). I am using cloud shell to run all the codes. In the guide, to make an annotate video request, I need to create a request.json file. 
[image]

Where to put this file once it's created?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request.json` file in this case should be saved in the same directory that you'll make the curl request from in step 2 of that guide. The curl command points to that file at the end:

```
curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
'https://videointelligence.googleapis.com/v1beta1/videos:annotate' \
-d @request.json
```

The `@request.json` means it's looking in the current directory for the file.